# Can I delete my account on one exchange, but keep my account on all other Stack Exchanges?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I have an account on multiple Stack Exchanges; I would like to delete my account on one site but keep it on the rest.

Is this possible?

Comment: This question might be better fit on [meta.se]. But yes, that's totally possible.

Comment: Refer [help center](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account)

Comment: If you want to clear anything and decide to change your mind, will be there to help.

Comment: I'm curious why you want to delete your account - if you'd like to discuss, start a chat room with me.  I'm at work at the moment, but I'd be happy to discuss any concerns you have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes, this is possible.

Account deletion is per-site, and I even know of several users who've quit one site completely but are still active on others.

From [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account):

> **If your account has never voted and has posted at most once** [on the relevant site], you should see a self-delete option on your user page under "Edit Profile & Settings":
>
> [image: screenshot]
>
> **If your account has posted more than once, or voted**, go to the [Contact Support page](https://movies.stackexchange.com/contact) and fill out the form. One of the items in the topics drop-down list is for account deletion.
>
> You can also get to that page via the "contact us" section on the site footer. Please note that account deletion is not instant. It might take several days for your request to be processed.
>
> Due to [a known issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155901/further-anonymize-deleted-accounts-by-changing-the-username-prior-to-deletion), you might want to change your username before deleting the account.
>
> Either of these procedures cover deleting your account on **one specific site**.
>
> **Content you've posted on the site** [is owned by you but licensed to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18221/who-owns-the-content-i-post), and you therefore cannot request that it be deleted with your account.

It's a bit scary to delete an account, since it always feels as though you might be deleting yourself from all sites, but don't worry - if you only press the delete button on one site, or submit a 'contact us' asking to be deleted only on one site, you won't suddenly disappear from Stack Exchange completely.